# What is the proper way to have unary relationship in EF-core code first?

Tags: c#, sqlite, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I have a Destination Entity, Which I made unary because a destination can have another destination.
E.g. Point A -> Point B -> Point C

I have tried creating the appropriate Entity class.

```
    public class Destination
    {
        public int DestinationId { get; set; }
        public Destination NextDestination { get; set; }
        public float Distance { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpectedArrival { get; set; }
        public DateTime ActualArrival { get; set; }
    }
```

There were no errors but what i get instead is

```
Destination
NextDestinationDestinationId
Distance
ExpectedArrival
ActualArrival
```

Is there anyway that I can make it like to call it like "Destination.NextDestinationId"

Comment: So, you want to customize the name of the generated foreign key?

Comment: Yes, but I get the error "member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Comment: And you are using code first?

Comment: Yes. then add-migration,update-database then I just view the diagram in MSSMS if its the same as my E-R diagram.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Destination
    {
        public int DestinationId { get; set; }
        public int PreviousDestinationId { get; set; }

        public virtual Destination Previous { get; set; }
        public virtual Destination Next{ get; set; }
    }

    public class DestinationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Destination>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Destination> builder)
        {
            builder
                .HasOne(p => p.Previous)
                .WithOne(p => p.Next)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.PreviousDestinationId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure custom foreign key name in fluent API:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<Destination>()
     .HasRequired(w => w.Destination)
     .WithMany()
     .Map(m => m.MapKey("NextDestinationId"));
}
```

This will name your column "NextDestinationId" instead of "NextDestinationDestinationId".

I don't know if you need `.WithMany()` or something else in configuration, that's up to you.